# Getting .hg not found with Mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Just the other day I was having some problems with my XCode project so I deleted all of the files in my project directory, downloaded my latest commit from BitBucket, and copied all the files from that directory into my empty project directory. Yes I know this was pretty dumb, but now when I try to make a new commit I get: .hg not found. Is it possible to fix this or have I permanently screwed over my repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole mercurial repository *usually* remains in your working folder, right under the sub-folder `.hg`. I say *usually*, because by deleting your working folder, you also deleted your repo, so yes, it *cannot be found* anymore. Simply downloading your latest state does not bring it back.

Don't worry, since you had the whole repo in Bitbucket, you only need to reclone. Make a manual backup of your current changes before doing so, if you don't want to loose them.